# SQL syntax: select only if more than X results

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I have a table with measurements called *measures*. The table has one column for the *location* and a second colum for a corresponding *value* (example is simplified).

The table looks like (note 2 entries for *loc1*):

```
location | value
-----------------
loc1     | value1
loc1     | value2
loc2     | value3
loc3     | value4
loc4     | value5
```

i now want to formulate a SQL query (actually i use sqlite) which only returns the first two rows of the table (i.e. loc+value1 and loc1+value2), because this location has more than one entry in this table.

the pseudotext formulation would be: show me the rows of the locations, which are present more than once in the whole table 
pseudcode:

```
SELECT * from measures WHERE COUNT(location over the whole table) > 1
```

the solution may be really simple, but somehow i seem not to crack the nut.

what i have so far is a SELECT statement, which returns locations which have more than one entry. as a next step i would need exactly all rows which correspond to the locations returned from this query:

```
SELECT location FROM measures GROUP BY location HAVING count(*) > 1
```

so as a next step i tried to do a JOIN with the same table and incorporate above query, but the results are incorrect. i tried it like this, but this is wrong:

```
select t1.location, t1.value
from 
     measures as t1
     join 
     measures as t2 on t1.location = t2.location 
group by
      t2.location 
having count(*) > 1
```

help is appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were right to use `HAVING`, and to think about using the self-join... just had the order of the operations slightly off...

```
select m1.location, m1.value
from measures m1
join (
  select location
  from measures
  group by location
  having count(*) > 1
) m2 on m2.location = m1.location
```

The sub-select gets all the locations that have more than one entry... and then this is joined to the table again to get the full results.

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bdf60/4)

Comment: Out of interest is there any difference in practical terms between this and the method of putting the subselect in a where clause rather than using join? I always think the where clause seems more readable and feels more natural to me but I don't know if there are performance differences or similar...

Comment: thanks! this works smoothly :) i am happy now. i think this type of query has many use-cases. at least i need it :)
and i also did not know SQL Fiddle. seems very good.
and yes, i'd be also interested in which solution is better or more practicable. the JOIN-solution or the nested query-solution?

Comment: and chris. see this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18108159/973158) for explanation of differences of both solutions. the JOIN solution lets you also display the number of duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

Use a nested select:

```
SELECT location,value,type,value_added
  FROM measures
  WHERE location IN
    (SELECT location FROM measures
      GROUP BY location HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

(Syntax is by memory, might be somewhat off)

Comment: this also works. seems a bit more intuitive for me than the JOIN solution. still, both yield the same results. thanks!

Comment: They are essentially equivalent, and the query planner/optimizer should execute them the same way. I say 'should' because I don't know sqlite at all...

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to get the list of locations that have more than one value.  The following uses `in` to fetch the records:

```
select m.*
from measures m
where m.location in (select location from measures group by location having count(*) > 1);
```

You can also formulate this with a join:

```
select m.*, mdup.numdups
from measures m join
     (select location, count(*) as numdups
      from measures
      group by location
      having count(*) > 1
     ) mdup
     on m.location = mdup.location;
```

One advantage to doing the query this way is that you can get the number of duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM measures WHERE
(location) IN (
    SELECT
        location
    FROM
        measures
    GROUP BY
        location
    HAVING
        COUNT(location) > 1
) ORDER BY ASC
```