# orientDB : Only show results / return something if a min of datasets is available

Tags: mysql, sql, orientdb

I've built a query generator to generate subquerys on which I can access specific data which is related to the user, but does not contain the user information directly.

**user->user_has_profiles->profile** The query will return profiles for example.

Since one user can have multiple profiles the amount of results of this query might be **amount_of_users * 0-n**

I'd like to only return results if at least 5 users where involved in my query.

I found this for sqlite / mysql [SQL syntax: select only if more than X results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108073/sql-syntax-select-only-if-more-than-x-results) but since neither join nor having is available for orientDB I'm interested if there is any solution for this.

Example part of the query

```
 select expand(rid) from (
   select person_id, last(rid) as rid from (
     select in('person_owns_profile').person_id[0] as person_id, @rid as rid, valid_from from (
       select from (
         ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with these records.

[image]

This is the graph.

[image]

I used this query

```
select from (select from profile)
let $b= (select count(*) from user)
where $b[0].count>5
```

[image]
[image]

Hope it helps.

UPDATE

You can use also this query

```
select from (select from profile) where "true" in (select if(eval(" count > 2"), "true", "false") from (select count(*) from user))
```

Comment: Checked it and it works :) thanks - sadly i'm using a framework to access to orient which is not able to use the syntax with let. But still the correct answer!

Comment: @FrankProvost I'm looking for a solution without using let

Comment: Can you try with "select from (select from profile) let $b= (select count(*) from user) where $b[0].count>5" as a unique string ?